# If $H=⟨a^m⟩$ and $K=⟨a^n⟩$ for $m,n\in\Bbb{N}$ and $a\in G$ for an infinite group $G$, then does $H\cap K=⟨a^{{\rm lcm}\{m,n\}}⟩$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $H=⟨a^m⟩$ and $K=⟨a^n⟩$ for $m,n\in\Bbb{N}$ and $a\in G$ for an infinite group $G$, then does $H\cap K=⟨a^{{\rm lcm}\{m,n\}}⟩$?

I'm trying to find a generator for the group $H\cap K$ with the given conditions, and I think that it's $a^{{\rm lcm}\{m,n\}}$, but I'm lost trying to prove it.

My argument is basically that the intersection will only include elements that are multiples of both $m$ and $n$, and the only way that all of those will be included is if the group is generated by the least common multiple.

But the way that I'm looking at it doesn't require that $G$ is infinite, which seems like a red flag to me.

I'm just wondering if this is a valid answer, and if there's a way to rigorously prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H\cap K=\langle a^l\rangle $. Then $m\mid l$ and $n\mid l$ implies $\text{lcm} (m,n)\mid l$. Also $a^{\text{lcm} (m,n)}\in H\cap K$, hence $l\mid \text{lcm} (m,n)$. Combining these two divisibilities we have $l=\pm \text{lcm}(m,n)$.